# Powershell - compare parts of two large XML files

Tags: xml, powershell, compare

I have two large (> 100MB,several million lines each) XML files that are structured as follows.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<index>
    <doc id='0'>
        <field name='PART' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>12345-678</val>
        </field>
        <field name='DESCRIPTION' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>Part XYX123 Description</val>
        </field>
        <field name='QTY' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>18</val>
        </field>
        <field name='VENDOR' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>ACME</val>
        </field>
        <field name='MFG' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val></val>
        </field>
    </doc>
    <doc id='1'>
        <field name='PART' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>ABCD-1234</val>
        </field>
        <field name='DESCRIPTION' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>PART ABCD Description</val>
        </field>
        <field name='QTY' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>4</val>
        </field>
        <field name='VENDOR' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val></val>
        </field>
        <field name='MFG' norm='-1' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val></val>
        </field>
    </doc>
</index>
```

I need to find items that are in one but not the other, and vice-versa.  Initially, I only want to compare the attribute `PART` value, but would like to also compare other values (Description, etc).

I want to determine if what's in xmlfile1:

```
index/doc/field name=part/val - 12345-678
```

is also in xmlfile2.  If not, write it out to a text/csv file.

I've tried using `Compare-Object` & `Get-Content`, but one of the issues that I've encountered are the other attributes that are in each XML file.  Both XML Files may have

```
index/doc/field name=part/val - 12345-678
```

but the difference is that xmlfile1 may have different values for the norm & flags attributes than xmlfile2.  Which makes using `Compare-Object` & `Get-Content` flag everything.

Using Powershell, how would you make a compare ignore the "noise" attributes, but match on the `<value>` only for the `PART` attribute?

**EDIT**

To clarify - the second XML file would be nearly identical to the one shown. However - what could be different would be the `<doc id='0'>` in either XML, the `<field name='PART'`  would be the same, but the other attributes `norm='-1'` and `flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>` could be different in each.  I would want to find the PART attribute, ignore the rest of the attributes in `field`, and determine if the contents in `<val>` exist in the second XML file.

Comment: Do you have a sample of xmlfile2? How would you know which elements to compare? Since you say PART-value MAY be the same, then that's useless. What's static? The doc-id's static?

Comment: @FrodeF.- I added some more info for clarity.  Attribute `name` would be static, but the others (`norm`, `flags`) could have different values.  Where attribute `name=PART`, I want to determine if what's in `<val>` is in XML file 2.  Ignore the rest of the attributes in that line.  Also, the value in `<doc id=` could be different (different order between the two).

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a better XML based answer that searches XPATHs or some such (I'm not an XML expert by any means), but what I would do if it were me is to convert it all to arrays of objects. If you don't mind dropping the norm, flags, or any other element aside from the field name and value, then you could do something like this:

```
[xml]$File1 = Get-Content c:\path\to\file1.xml
[xml]$File2 = Get-Content c:\path\to\file2.xml
$File1Objs = ForEach($Item in $File1.index.doc){
    $Obj=[PSCustomObject]@{'id'=$Item.id}
    $Item.field|%{
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -NotePropertyName $_.Name -NotePropertyValue $_.val}
    $Obj
}
$File2Objs = ForEach($Item in $File2.index.doc){
    $Obj=[PSCustomObject]@{'id'=$Item.id}
    $Item.field|%{
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -NotePropertyName $_.Name -NotePropertyValue $_.val}
    $Obj
}
Compare-Object $File1Objs $File2Objs -Property Part -PassThru | Where{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}|Select * -Exclude SideIndicator | Export-CSV c:\temp\File1Only.txt
Compare-Object $File1Objs $File2Objs -Property Part -PassThru | Where{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}|Select * -Exclude SideIndicator | Export-CSV c:\temp\File2Only.txt
```

Like I said, there may well be a more efficient answer, but this should be effective none the less.

Comment: I'd need a more efficient answer.  With 2 large XML files, `Get-Content` gives an `Out of Memory` error before I can load the first XML file.  Works fine for small files.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same type of solution as @TheMadTechnician's answer, but it does require a bit of memory (at least when you have big files). However there are ways to optimize it. You say it runs out of memory at `Get-Content`. `Get-Content` creates an object-array with a string per line. Since we're going to cast it to an xml-document anyways, we can read the file as a simple string which should save us alot of memory.

If it still has problems, you may want to run this script on a computer with more resources. XML-parsing is easier when we can save the whole file to memory to begin with.

```
$xml = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\path\to\file1.xml"))
$File1Objs = $xml.index.doc | ForEach-Object {
    $Obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{"ID" = $_.id}
    $_.field | ForEach-Object { Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.val }
    $Obj
}
#Throw out the garbage
$xml = $null
[gc]::Collect()

$xml = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\path\to\file2.xml"))
$File2Objs = $xml.index.doc | ForEach-Object {
    $Obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{"ID" = $_.id}
    $_.field | ForEach-Object { Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.val }
    $Obj
}

#Throw out the garbage
$xml = $null
[gc]::Collect()

#One compare to save resources. Compare PART and Description-property (to show off multiple-property-comparison)
$comparison = Compare-Object $File1Objs $File2Objs -Property Part, Description -PassThru

$comparison | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | Select-Object -Property * -Exclude SideIndicator | Export-CSV -Path "c:\path\to\File1Only.txt" -NoTypeInformation
$comparison | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } | Select-Object -Property * -Exclude SideIndicator | Export-CSV -Path "c:\path\to\File2Only.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also use a hashtable-based solution where you store the values from file1 and compare the values with when you read file2. Ex:

```
#Read as single string to save memory
$text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\users\frode\Test.txt")

#Hashtable to store PART-value from file1
$PART = @{}
#Regex to extract PART-value
[regex]::Matches($text,"(?s)doc id='(?<ID>.*?)'>.*?'PART' norm.*?val>(?<PART>.*?)<\/val>") |
ForEach-Object {
    #Store PART-value in hashtable with doc-id as key
    $PART.Add($_.Groups["ID"].Value,$_.Groups["PART"].Value)
}

$text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\users\frode\Test2.txt")
[regex]::Matches($text,"(?s)doc id='(?<ID>.*?)'>.*?'PART' norm.*?val>(?<PART>.*?)<\/val>") |
ForEach-Object {
    #Check if docid was in file1
    if($PART.ContainsKey($_.Groups["ID"].Value)) {
        #If in file1, check if value is different
        if($PART[$_.Groups["ID"].Value] -ne $_.Groups["PART"].Value) {
            "MISMATCH in DocID '$($_.Groups["ID"].Value)' - File1 PART: '$($PART[$_.Groups["ID"].Value])' - File2 PART: '$($_.Groups["PART"].Value)'"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MISMATCH in DocID '0' - File1 PART: '12345-678' - File2 PART: '12345-6789'
MISMATCH in DocID '1' - File1 PART: 'ABCD-1234' - File2 PART: 'ABCD-1235'
```

This is just a proof-of-concept using regex. With a text-parsing solution like this (using ex. hashtables to store values) you could use `StreamReader` to read one line at a time to minimize memory usage.